# E3D V6 PLA prints leaning / not square

Tags: pla, troubleshooting, e3d-v6

When printing a 1 cm test cube after upgrading to the V6 the cubes are tilted ever so slightly. This does not happen with the stock MK8 hotend, or when printing with the V6 with Polycarbonate+Carbonfiber, so it is not a mechanical problem; it seems to be limited to PLA.

Searching forums for this is no help as everyone says to check to make sure the frame is square, etc..

What would cause this? Thanks!

A picture has been added, but it is difficult to see the problem in the picture because of the inherent problems with photographing shapes in general, but here are some examples. The grey is PLA and the black is PC+carbon. The black one is acceptably square while the grey is not. The picture may not accurately convey this but trust me.

I have tried slowing the speed down, everywhere between 60-20 mm/s, it did not help. Temp between 180-210 °C, bed between 60-70 °C.

For the PC+carbon the temp is much higher of course, around 260-270 °C and the bed is 90-100 °C, print speed 40 mm/s.

[image]

Comment: Also, what printer, print speed and temperature? What kind of infil and perimeter settings do you use? It looks like you also overextrude the PLA. Different materials use different settings - what forks for one material does *not* work for another.

Comment: The tilting is only on the V6, it does not happen with the MK8 hotend. This is an E3d problem and one I can’t believe is unique to me. Also the overextension is due to the flow settings which must be increased to get a good first layer, also limited to the v6 with pla, but that is unrelated to the tilting. And that is another thread entirely